# Как скопировать данные таблиц во вторую базу данных SQLite?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Я копирую базу данных `firstDB.db` и задаю ей имя `secondDB.db`. В первой базе данных содержатся 5 таблиц и в одной из них заполнено одно поле. После копирования все проходит успешно: создается база данных (но вместе с файлом базы данных почему-то создается файл `secondDB.db-journal`), а в базе создаются те же 5 таблиц, но вот поле не заполняется!

Копирую через:

```
    File databaseFile = new File(((ChoiceDictionary) getActivity()).getDatabasePath("firstDB.db").getAbsolutePath());
    File oldDatabaseFile = new File(databaseFile.getParentFile(), "secondDB.db");
```

Comment: Данные из одной базы достаёте, в другую вставляете.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, а через файлы это никак нельзя сделать?(

Comment: Попробуйте вот так копировать: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9293885/3212712

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, я уже придумал другой способ, пока шел с тренировки... Базы данных и имена выводимых пользователю теперь две разные строки. А раньше было `name` имя выводимое пользователю, а `name.replace(" ", "_") + ".db"` — база данных. Теперь обошелся вообще без копирования, но пришлось вспомнить работу с двойными массивами... Добавьте Ваш первый комментарий в ответ, я его приму.